# Getting Exception : "replication slot "XXX" is active for PID XXX`" on deploying service on kubernetes with RollingUpdate deployment strategy

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I've an application which use debezium-postgres connector to publish events on kafka from postgres. Application is working fine if kubernetes deployment strategy is Recreate.
**But Throwing exception on using RollingUpdate Deployment strategy**

- Exception `replication slot "XXX" is active for PID XXX` as older pod is using the same replication slot

Application is using PGOUTPUT debezium plugin and some postgres configuration are as follow:

```
max_wal_senders = 4
max_replication_slots = 4
wal_level = logical
wal_receiver_timeout = 300s
wal_sender_timeout = 300s
```

Is there any configuration which might help to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot start two WAL sender processes with the same replication slot.

If you need two clients to run logical decoding, create two replication slots. Otherwise, make sure that any client who uses the replication slot is stopped before you connect.

Comment: Will there be any impact on performance if I create two replication slot for same db and switching slots in connector service only when new deployment is done?

Comment: A replication slot has no performance impact (but it can cause your disk to fill up). What takes resources is logical decoding. If you use two WAL senders, the impact will be twice as much.